# Function is not calling on onclick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, this, arrow-functions

Here I simply want to call a `walletconnect` function when I click on the button. but it is not calling any function. please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal";


class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      address: ''

    }
    
    const connector = new WalletConnect({
      bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
      qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
    });
  }

  walletConnectFunc = async () => {
    const connector = new WalletConnect({
      bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
      qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
    });
    if (connector.connected) {
      alert("already connected")
      return
    }
    connector.createSession();
    connector.on("connect", async (error, payload) => {
      console.log("connect")
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      // Get provided accounts and chainId
      const { accounts, chainId } = payload.params[0];
      console.log("connect account", accounts)
      console.log("chainid account", chainId)

      const obj = {
        "address": accounts[0],

      }
      this.setState({ address: obj.address })
      console.log(this.state.address)
      alert(this.state.address)
    })


  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary my-4" type="button" onClick={() => this.walletConnectFunc()}>WalletConnect</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If more code is required then tell me in a comment section. I will update my question with that information.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? What happens when you click the button? And btw `onClick{(() => this.something()}` can be changed to `onClick={this.something}` to avoid creating an extra function in the render.

Comment: Also is there a reason that method is `async` when you're not `await`ing anything in it?

Comment: Same goes for the callback to `onnector.on` — `async` is for when you have things you want to `await` rather than using Promise `.then` syntax, you don't need to throw `async`s on functions otherwise.

Comment: @ZacAnger can you filter out my code coz i'm new with typescript and its literally my first app.tsx. i dont have such strong grip on ts concepts

Comment: I just want to call that walletconnect function , you can add an other function as well just for testing. in case something wrong with walletconnect package

Comment: A good place to start is by removing the `async` keywords, removing the extra inline arrow function in the onclick (see my first comment), and adding console.logs and/or `debugger` statements all throughout that function and keeping an eye on your browser devtools. You can also remove the `new Walletconnector` initialization from your constructor, it's not doing anything there since you're not putting it on `this` or anything.

Comment: Your code actually runs just fine even with those issues though — I just copy-pasted it into a CodeSandbox and there are no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly,** you should remove the redundant `async` keyword, Just `walletConnectFunc()` is enough. Simply because, inside your function do not call any `await` keyword, So that does not make sense.

**Secondly,** You just listen to event onClick like `onClick={this.walletConnectFunc}` to avoid creating an extra function in the render (As @Zac Anger's recommendation)

**Finally,** in case you have to access `this` inside the function, use `arrow function` or you can also bind `this` context like this way (For me, I highly recommend using the third way for the performance aspect)

**In short,** Just need to use `arrow function` when using `context`.
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: ""
    };

    this.walletConnectFuncAsync = this.walletConnectFuncAsync.bind(this);
  }

  async walletConnectFuncAsync() {
    await this.sleep(1000);
  }

  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => alert("Woke up after " + ms + "ms"), ms);
    });
  }

  walletConnectFunc() {
    alert(123);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary my-4"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.walletConnectFunc}
          >
            WalletConnect
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary my-4"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.walletConnectFuncAsync}
          >
            WalletConnect_Async
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo on Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-firefly-ilbgi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: functions are calling perfectly but the inner code is not working . Inner code which you can see for address and qrcode functions and walletconnect bridge

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your are missing here is to bind the class method. You only have to write the binding method on the constructor like this:

```
...
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      address: ''
    }
   this.walletConnectFunc = this.walletConnectFunc.bind(this);
...
```

Comment: Doesn't using the arrow function automatically do this ?

Comment: Correct @LeonBoehmer.

Comment: Nice! I'll keep the answer to share this knowledge. Thank, guys!

Comment: @Gust Check [my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrkJs.png) with a more detailed explanation about `arrow function` vs `this context` :D